# Proof in linear algebra. About functions and matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

I struggling with proving linear algebra proofs. I just don't get it sometimes for the generalization, only particular cases, and I don't see how to apply the theory or how to get more information.

Let $F\in L(K^n,K^m)$ a bijective function. If  $A=M(f)$ proof that $A$ is invertible and that $A^{-1}=M(f^{-1})$

I know if $A$ is a invertible matrix, B exists such that $AB$ and $BA$ are identical matrices. Also I don't know where the fact that it's a bijective function works here. I'd appreciate any help, and any tips to get better at this proofs.

Comment: $A$ encodes $f$ in terms of the canonical basis of $K^n$. What is the encoding of $f^{-1}$? What happens when you multiply $M(f) M(f^{-1})$? $M(f \circ f^{-1})$?

Comment: I don't know, I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that you really need are the properties of the matrix associated to a linear map. Let $M(\mathbb K,m,n)$ denote the vector space of the $m\times n$ matrices with entries from the field $\mathbb K$. Define the map
$$
\Phi_{n,m}: L(\mathbb K^n,\mathbb K^m) \rightarrow M(\mathbb K,m,n)
$$
in such a way that $\Phi(f)$ is the matrix associated to $f$ with respect to the canonical basis (you can also choose another basis and the argument holds as well). The map $\Phi_{n,m}$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces, and for all $F\in L(\mathbb K^n,\mathbb K^m)$ and $G\in L(\mathbb K^m,\mathbb K^p)$ then
$$
\Phi_{n,p}(G\circ F) = \Phi_{m,p}(G)\cdot \Phi_{n,m}(F).
$$

---

Let $F\in L(\mathbb K^n,\mathbb K^m)$ and let $A=\Phi_{n,m}(F)$ be the associated matrix. If $F$ is invertible then there exists $G\in L(\mathbb K^m,\mathbb K^n)$ such that
$$
F\circ G = Id_{\mathbb K^m} \quad\text{and}\quad G\circ F = Id_{\mathbb K^n}.
$$
Let $B\in M(\mathbb K,n,m)$ be the matrix associated to $G$. From the properties of $\Phi$, the above equations become
$$
AB=I_m\quad\text{and}\quad BA=I_n.
$$
This proves that $A$ is invertible and that its inverse is the matrix associated with $G=F^{-1}$.